# Nginx : rewrite request for 'p.test-prd.com.local' to 'www.test.com'

Tags: nginx, configuration, rewrite

For various reasons, we follow an internal DNS scheme where the internal test site for 'www.test.com' would be 'p.test-tst.com.local'. I won't go into the details why we ended up with the scheme we're using.

Now, I could add 'p.test-tst.com.local', 'p.test-tst.de.local', 'p.test-tst.co.uk.local' (and so on) to the Nginx configuration file for this specific test site. However, Isn't there a more flexible way of doing this? Could I somehow make Nginx accept 'p.test.tst.com.local', and have it to rewrite that internally to 'www.test.com' so that the website (running on Drupal) would think that the request came for 'www.test.com'?

One of the main reasons why this would be nice is that I then would not have to think about adding more logic to Drupal when it comes to language handling (setting a language for 'com.local').

Comment: What mechanisms are used by nginx to communicate with drupal? Fastcgi (like php-fpm) or proxy to other webserver?

Comment: We're using php-fpm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you currectly you need something like this:

`map $http_host $name {
        hostnames;
        p.test.tst.com.local   test.com;
        ...
    }
    ...
    server {
    ...
        location / {
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock
             include fastcgi_params
             fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $name;
    }`

This will set HTTP_HOST variable in $SERVER to test.com if actual requested hostname was p.test.tst.com.local. Drupal looks at $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] value to determine a hostname.
You can add other mappings to `map {}` so it's quite flexible.

Comment: This means i still need to add 'p.test.tst.com.local' to server_name, doesn't it? No way to get around that one, is it?

Comment: If incoming request goes to the correct `server {}` without a server_name then no, you don't. In my example `map` just looks into HTTP HOST header (not into $server_name variable) and assigns a value to $name. Then you can use $name how you want. For example for setting HTTP_HOST variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your site to answer to these Hosts values then you have no choice, you must put them in the `server_name` directive (you could use wildcard or regex to make the conf shorter).

```
server {

    server_name www.test.com;
    include /path/to/server_names;

    [ ... ]

    location / {
        [ ... ]
        fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST "www.test.com";
    }

}
```

File /path/to/server_names :

```
server_name p.test-tst.co.uk.local;
server_name p.test-tst.de.local;
```

Comment: Alright, so server_name can be used multiple times?

Comment: @sbrattla Of course.

Comment: But the same does not apply to the http directive, i assume. That is, i need to put the map of hostnames in the global http directive?

Comment: @sbrattla Which directive are you talking about?

Comment: He means a `http {}` block and my map I think solution but I have no idea how is that related to your solution

Comment: @Glueon Well, both are unrelated ways to make it work :)

Comment: You are right, http is not related to your answer...I should have asked about this on Glueon's answer.